# How to keep whitespace formatting in markdown/streamlit

Tags: python, frontend, markdown, chatbot, streamlit

I am trying to print out a chessboard inside a streamlit message. I am trying to print it inside a code block, but the whitespaces don't align as in the terminal. Is there any way to solve this issue?

This is how the chessboard now looks inside the chat:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mm0g.png) is how the chessboard now looks inside the chat

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Mzj.png) is an example of what I am trying to print out

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible code?

Answer (score 1):

I've re-created a simple layout of the chessboard according to the image that you've provided. The essence is to use `st.text` which is supports fixed-width space formatting.

Here is an example code snippet:

```
st.text('''
8  ♖ ♘ ♚ ♙ ♘
7    ♚     ♙
6      ♖
5        ♙
4          ♙
3  ♘
2        ♚
1  ♖
   a b c d e 
''')
```

And this produces the following in a Streamlit app:
[image]

Hope this helps.